# downloading images with aiohttp get stuck after some iteration

Tags: python, python-3.7, aiohttp, python-asyncio

I am using `aiohttp` to download some image files asynchronously. my code is:

```
async def save_message_images(self, message_data, channel):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        image_links = []
        for i, link in enumerate(message_data.get('image_links')):
            async with session.get(link) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    file_name = 'media/messages_images/' + str(channel.telegram_username) + '_' + \
                               str(message_data.get('message_id') + '_' + str(i)) + '.jpg'
                    file = open(file_name, mode='wb')
                    file.write(await response.read())
                    file.close()
                    image_links.append(file_name)
                else:
                    raise MessageWebCrawler.RetrieveUrlException()
        message_data['image_links'] = image_links
        await session.close()
        return message_data
```

I run this code in a `while` block, but after some iteration `aiohttp` gets stuck and does not work anymore. I am using `python 3.7.4` and `aiohttp 3.5.4` in `ubuntu 16`. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: did find any solution for this?

Comment: @d02d33pak I do not exactly remember what I did, but I think it was not aiohttp problem. I think the main problem was that I was running the program in the daemon which stopped after some minutes or some hours. I used `screen` in ubuntu and everything works now.